# The server tag is not well formed or BC30201: Expression expected

Tags: asp.net, server-tags

I read all the posts about this problem but it did not help me. I tried different ways to solve this problem, if I do it like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button_Save" class="btnSave" runat="server" Text="<%# GetLabelName(objUserSession.lngLanguageID, "Button_Save")%>" />
```

i have this problem: **The server tag is not well formed**. If like that:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button_Save" class="btnSave" runat="server" Text="<%# GetLabelName(objUserSession.lngLanguageID, 'Button_Save')%>" />
```

i have another problem: **BC30201: Expression expected**. And if like that:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button_Save" class="btnSave" runat="server" Text='<%# GetLabelName(objUserSession.lngLanguageID, "Button_Save")%>' />
```

my result is: `<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$Button_Save" value="" id="MainContent_Button_Save" class="btnSave">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very good solution to this problem, it is here: [THE CODEEXPRESSIONBUILDER](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your third option is the usual way it's done.  Are you certain that, with those specific parameters, your function is returning a non-null, non-empty value?

Comment: I'm sure, because the checked and tried a different value, which works in a different place (who not is runat="server")

Comment: Of course I can do it on the server side like this: 
`Button_Save.Text = GetLabelName(objUserSession.lngLanguageID, "Button_Save")`, but i need do it on client side!

Comment: Is objUserSession protected or public, and scoped at the class level?

Comment: obUserSession is public and it is in a module (.vb)

Comment: I'm curious:  if you were to bind `objUserSession.lngLanguageID` to the `text` field of an `asp:Label` control, what would it render as?  I'm wondering if the problem is with `objUserSession`, with `GetLabelName`, or with something else.

Comment: I'm giving you example, when i do this:
`<div id="Title"><%= GetLabelName(objUserSession.lngLanguageID, "Title")%></div>`
i have this result on the html page:
`<div id="lblTitle">Users Permissions</div>`
it works very well!

Comment: Did you notice that in your example (the one that works) you used the `<%= %>` syntax rather than the `<%# %>` syntax?  It looks as if you can *evaluate* that expression, but you can't necessarily *bind* to it.